# Why are my js.erb views not working when using webpacker in Rails 6 with bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

Im trying to add som simple Ajax to my rails app. I am using Bootstrap with webpack.
My `webpack/environment.js` file looks like this

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

My `javascript/packs/application.js` looks like this

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
import 'bootstrap'
import 'src/main'
import 'style/main'
```

I'm trying to add some Ajax for one of my models in `create.js.erb`

```
$("#question-<%= @exam_option.exam_question.id %>-options").append("<%= escape_javascript render 'exam_option', option: @exam_option %>");
$('#add_option_modal').modal('hide');
```

When I try and add one of my options, I get the console error

`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $`

I've searched for a solution and have been unsuccessful.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

**Edit:**

When I added Bootstrap to my app, I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@adrian_teh/ruby-on-rails-6-with-webpacker-and-bootstrap-step-by-step-guide-41b52ef4081f) . When following the guide, I installed bootstrap, jquery and popper.js with yarn

`yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js`

The jQuery that Bootstrap uses is working correctly (such as tooltips).
as per @mechnicov's answer, I tried changing my `environment.js` to

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)
```

and I added `require("jquery")` above `import 'bootstrap'` in my `application.js`

when I made those changes, my code in `create.js.erb` works correctly, but it makes my Bootstrap not function correctly and throw errors such as `TypeError: ... $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() undefined`.

**Edit 2**

As per the accepted answer, I changed my `application.js` to :

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery')
import 'bootstrap'
import 'src/main'
import 'style/main'
```

All seems to be working correctly, but I'm unsure why I need to add it this way? isn't Webpack supposed to do this from my `environment.js` file?
If someone can explain this, please do.

Comment: Got a similar problem (and below answer didn't help): Where do you put the create.js.erb? 
In  /app/javascript/pack    --or--  /app/views/blabla  ? 
And do I need to include with a javascript_pack_tag?
Thanks

Comment: Typically In the views folder for the model/controller you are working with. You can also call it in a different directory by doing something like ‘format.js { render ‘folder_name/create.js.erb }’ and replace “folder_name” with the view directory it’s located in. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try below code :-

```
# javascript/packs/application.js

window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery')
```

**OR**

```
# javascript/packs/application.js

require("jquery")
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

I was also facing same problem but above code was worked for me at that time

Hope this will help you also. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I put this code?

Comment: I have just edited my answer..you can re-check... :)

Answer (score 3):

> All seems to be working correctly, but I'm unsure why I need to add it
> this way? isn't Webpack supposed to do this from my environment.js
> file? If someone can explain this, please do.

I'm going to answer your question based on the edit you have done in your question, what you have to understand is how webpack works, basically you have:

1 - an entry file which is your source code file (that contains "imports" and/or other javascript code)

2 - Webpack takes that entry file, bundle it, and produces an output file. In your application, this is what you end up using, the final output/bundle.

In Rails, Webpacker is the gem that configures webpack for you out of the box and hides the boring details from you so you can just jump and start using it.

In term of webpacker any file you put in `javascript/packs` is considered as **an entry file**, by default we have `application.js` there, so `app/javascript/packs/application.js` is your entry file, the output file will have the same name with a hash string attached to it, something like this `application-ff14101dff18182f89f6.js`

Let's imagine you add another file to app/javascript/packs called admin.js (which is another entry file), what will happen is that Webpacker is configured to make an output file from each entry file. That means after compilation, you will have another file `admin-ff14101dff18182f89f6.js` as output.

The output files are placed under `/packs/js` in your Rails application, and you can call them from layout as follows:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'admin', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %
```

You can even use the first tag in your `layouts/application.html.erb` and the second one in another layout, for example, `layouts/admin.html.erb`, you don't have to push all your code in one giant application.js (yep you can make your site faster by loading only the necessary scripts).

Now that you understand the basics, it's time **to answer your question** as we said before Webpacker is using any JS file in **app/javascript/packs** as an entry file, you can verify this by opening **config.webpacker.yml** file, and locate the following:

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs // <------ The location of the entry files
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs // <------ The location of the output/bundle
  ...
```

So even when you are exposing jQuery in `environment.js` via the ProvidePlugin, it's meant to be available for the webpack configured source path which is `app/javascript` only. That explains why you cannot access jquery from `app/views/some-view-folder/create.js.erb`.

You may ask, can expose the view folder `app/views/some-view-folder` to webpack somehow? Theoretically yes, by "resolving" that folder which webpacker has a configuration for it (see config/webpacker.yml):

```
# Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
# ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
resolved_paths: []
```

It's possible to do something like `resolved_paths: ['app/views/some-view-folder']` which means if you import create.js.erb in your application.js webpack will be able to find that file and import it, however practically it doesn't make any sense as create.js.erb needs to be executed at run time and execute other ruby code from your application and it's used to render a view dynamically not for a static purpose like a JS file does (sorry I don't know much about Rails internal but you got the idea)

By doing `window.jQuery = window.$ = $` you are exposing jQuery to the window object, which makes it a global, but you can always use a regular ajax request in a file under `app/javascript` instead of relying on something like `remote: true` depending on if you want to expose things globally or not.

I hope this was somehow useful, I have written a book for beginners about webpack which you can check on [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484258959) or on [apress](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484258958) if that interests you, that will give you a full understanding how webpack works whether you are working with Rails or any other framework :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't load JQuery.

Add it to your node modules:

```
$ yarn add jquery
```

Write right path to JQuery in `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Add line before bootstrap in `javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("jquery")
```

And don't forget about `javascript_pack_tag 'application'` in main layout view.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my question to provide more info.